# Publish to different pubsub topic in Google cloud via mosquitto broker?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I have a pubsub topic name

```
projects/project_name/topics/Sandbox_PubSub
```

and I also have a subscription on that topic.
and then I have a cloud function name `Sandbox_function` which triggers with a `publish` on that topic.

I have a python code where I am publishing the data to this topic via a mosquitto broker

```
'/devices/device_id/events/Sandbox_PubSub'
```

Its working perfectly fine and I am receiving data in the cloud function as well as in the subscription.

Now I created another topic name

```
projects/project_name/topics/Pairing
```

and then subscription and another cloud function called `Pairing_Function` 
Now when I `publish` my data on

```
'/devices/device_id/events/Pairing'
```

Instead of getting that data in `Pairing_Function` I am getting the data in `Sandbox_Function` as a subFolder `Pairing` and also in `Sandbox_Subscription` instead of `Pairing` subscription.

What i am doing wrong here? and how can i get data into different topics?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it that we need to define the topics in the registry too.

(see: IoT core -> Registry Edit -> Add more telemetry topics)

We need to redirect the subFolder to specific topics